# What does "Beets and potatoes" mean?

Tags: meaning

During completion of World War, CIA director Philip Allen says to Edward:

> Philip: In every liberated country, there will be a battle between us
> and the Russians for their hearts and minds. Since we dropped the
> bomb, they're feeling a little short between the legs. The Russians
> still live in the 19th century. **Beets and potatoes**.

What does "Beets and potatoes" mean?

Comment: The reference is to vegetables and the subsistence economy in which they were once grown. https://www.askdifference.com/beetroot-vs-beet/

Comment: @RonaldSole They means who? Russians?

Comment: _They_ means vegetables.

Comment: Beets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetroot ; Potatoes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure a war gets _completed_. Though I suppose if only one side shows up it's **in**complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Farming is considered less "advanced" than manufacturing, and vegetable farming is considered less "advanced" than meat farming. Beets and potatoes are relatively cheap, but rather bland, and are associated with subsistence farming. So Allen is using them as shorthand for especially "primitive" economic activity; beets and potatoes are a "primitive" type of plant agriculture, plant agriculture is a "primitive" form of agriculture, and agriculture in general is a "primitive" industry.